# Xcode import local Swift Package and build from the app

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12, xcode-workspace, xcode12.5

The goal is to import a local Swift Package "Shared" into a Xcode project and have them both in a workspace.

I have created a workspace, dragged and dropped both the package and the project in, and then added the package to the app by adding it to Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.

This works when building from the workspace! But I have to make it also possible to build from the app project, currently it throws: "Missing package product 'Shared'".

I know it is possible to do what I want because I have an example project where it works, in there Shared is listed as a local Swift Package in the app project, in mine it is not. In the project Shared is listed under Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content but can't be added again after removing the reference.

It would be great if someone could help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a local Swift Package in the app project and to import the Shared Package there. Then it will be available in the whole project.